# UIViewController viewDidAppear after dismiss?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I have an app that uses a storyboard. I am going from the "main view controller" to the others using standard segues, and I am dismissing the other viewControllers with dismissViewController. (note, they are mostly being displayed in form sheet).

Thing is, when it returns to the main view controller, I need to do some cleanup (clear out arrays, reload a tableview and so on). How would I go about doing this, since i cannot use viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Comment: So, why can't you use viewDidAppear?

Comment: yeah not sure why you cant use `viewDidAppear`, but maybe you can use `- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` on the view you are coming from, to do it instead?

Comment: viewDidAppear is not getting called when i go back from a form sheet. Dunno why, but it doesn't. Think it is coz the view controller is always visible on form sheets.
I could use viewDidDisappear, but again, don't think it will be called when going to form sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution it is add block (for example closeActionBlock) for your presented controller and call this block when you hide controller. (How it is implement you can see in [Objective-C Block Property with Xcode code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121466/objective-c-block-property-with-xcode-4-code-completion))